# camel spring boot - exchange issue

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I am having an issue getting the "myHeaderValue" during the insert statement below using Camel/spring boot.
When I run the program I see on the console "Processed value from header is : one", however I receive an exception error camel exchange delivery exception.
The reason for the expection is the ":#myHeaderValue" is not populating in the query below. If I understand camel, I thought the header persisted and was passed to the endpoints.

Please advise me on how I can pass the #myHeaderValue to the insert end point.

springBootVersion: 1.5.4.RELEASE
camel:2.19.1

```
from("sql:SELECT columnOne, columnTwo from t_item"
            + "?consumer.initialDelay=3000"
            + "&consumer.delay=3000"
            + "&outputClass=mypackage.model.Item")
        .process(itemProcessor)
        .log("Processed value from header is : ${header.myHeaderValue}")
        .log("insert into t_item(columnOne, columnTwo) VALUES(${header.myHeaderValue}, 'two'")
        .to("sql:insert into t_item(columnOne) SELECT 'data' FROM t_store whhere header = :#myHeaderValue")
        .log("Row inserted")
        .end();
```

// from itemProcessor

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    exchange.getIn().setHeader("myHeaderValue", "one");
}
```

Comment: You should most likely write headers.myHeaderValue. Note the "s" in headers.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I used a more complex (INSERT ... SELECT) statement it fails, so I assume camel does NOT support INSERT ... SELECT. That said I was able to modify my code to a more simplistic insert query. All said, camel was getting the headers the query insert was the problem.

.to("sql:insert into t_item(columnOne, columnTwo) VALUES(:#myHeaderValue, 'two')");